# Display created component without coding

Tags: c#, winforms

Goal:
Display the created and customized control library component in the mainform screen

Problem:
I don't know how to display it without using drop, drag and click ability.

I want to display the component via coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty straightforward. You have just to instantiate the component and then to add it in your form `Controls` property.

```
/* Inside an event */
var component = new MyNamespace.MyComponent(/*whatever*/);
this.Controls.Add(component);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a handler for Load event of your form and instantiate whatever controls you want to display. Then add them to form's Controls collection.
Example:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Control c = new MyCustomControl();
    //customize size, position, etc of your control
    this.Controls.Add(c);
}
```

Comment: I tried using your code and I can't see the component being displayed in the GUI

Comment: Make sure the Visible property is true. Also, the code above will add the control to your form. If you have another control, like a Panel that is already contained in your form, this Panel might prevent your new added control to be visible. In this case add your control to the Panel or whatever control might be.